# backbone js , binding model to view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying out backbonejs but got stuck on how to bind the model to the view.

```
yepnope({
    load : ["/static/js/lib/jquery-1.6.2.min.js", "/static/js/lib/underscore-min.js", "/static/js/lib/backbone-min.js"],
    complete: nameList
});

function nameList() { 
    var PageItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
                                    defaults: {name: "default name" }
    }); 
    var Page = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: PageItem 
    });     
    var page = new Page;

    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#names"),
        $artistList: $('#names_list'),
        $inputField: $('input#new_name'),
        events: { 
            "keypress input": "processKeyPress" 
        },
        processKeyPress: function(event){
            if(event.charCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.addName();   
             }   
        }, 
        addName: function(event) {
                   var newName = this.$inputField.val(); 
                   this.$artistList.prepend('<li>' + newName + '</li>');
                   page.push(new  PageItem({name: newName})); 
                   // I've also tried page.push({name: newName});                                                                                                                                                  
    }       }); 
    var app = new AppView;}
```

When I press enter on the input field, it runs processKeyPress which calls addName, the new name is added the the html list but not pushed onto the model. I keep getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a){return new l(a)} has no method 'isObject'
```

Comment: ok.. weird.. using "add" instead of "push" works..

Comment: omg. ok. sorry. I'm going to bed. yes, I was wrong again.. the jsfiddle I forked was using an ancient backbone which gave rather different results.. good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, please test this out for yourself, but it appears to work with the Github version of underscore so maybe there was a bug which has been fixed.. http://jsfiddle.net/yjZVd/6/

Comment: Wow can't believe that works. The 'good' version of underscore: `https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/raw/master/underscore-min.js`